# Carousel images are not displayed correctly

Tags: jquery, css, flickity

I am using flickity library to display a lot of carousells on one page: https://spielraum-maybaum.ch/produkte/

But the first time I am loading a page the carousell images are not displayed completely, there is only one little stripe.

I think this must be a syntax or css error and want to know if you could help me figure this out.

I'm using wordpress. Plesase ask, if something is not clear.

Best
Lukas

Comment: DIV.flickity-viewport containing images have 24px height only. Try to fix that will bring the images properly visible. Your script is not calculating dynamic height of carousal.

Comment: Try setting `imagesLoaded: true`

Comment: `imagesLoaded: true` that made it, thank you very much!